# Looking for Author/Pulp-title of Fantasy/Sci-Fi short-story circa 1955

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, pulp

Been searching since early 90’s.

Theme: Man dies - consciousness transferred to future where women make Playmen from recycled organs.

Read when I was about 15 and it stuck with me.

Can only remember: love-make; goad; rolling-road; mental food creation via creation-space.

Reason: have screenplay and don’t want to plagiarise.

Don’t think it's a Playboy short-story?

Comment: Loads of extra info here ; http://www.sffworld.com/forum/threads/unusual-short-sf-f-story.367/

Comment: https://www.overdrive.com/media/2569044/recycle

Comment: Thanks BC, yes I found the sources you cited. Many thanks.

Comment: Is this your work? https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/251279

Comment: And I assume this is you as well; https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/563668/?

Comment: Yes BC. Been searching for a long time. You found me quick! Wish I could find my search-author as quick. I'll keep going. Thanks.

Comment: Theres lots of extra info in these links that you haven't included in your question.